# NSString not drawing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, nsstring, eaglview

I am trying to draw an NSString, but it won't render for some reason.

```
- (void)renderScene {
    // Make sure we are renderin to the frame buffer
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

    // Clear the color buffer with the glClearColor which has been set      
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Render the game Scene 
    if(gameState == 0){

        //MENU
        [menu renderAtPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0) centerOfImage: NO];

    } else if(gameState == 1){

        //GAMEPLAY

        [bk renderAtPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0) centerOfImage: NO];

        [self drawScore];

        [player draw];

        [squares render];

        [scoreString drawAtPoint: CGPointMake(262, 250) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size: 1.0f]]; //RIGHT HERE IS THE DRAW STRING

    } else if(gameState ==2){

        //DEATH SCREEN

        [squared renderAtPoint: CGPointMake(0, 0) centerOfImage: NO];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix Core Graphics and OpenGL. One simple way to get around this is to create a child window (UIView or a UILabel) and then set the text string in the child. You can set the transparency of the child view as well.

There are other ways (like drawing to a bitmap and then using that as an OpenGL texture, or using OpenGL to draw the fonts as bitmaps or outlines), but they are more work - depends on your needs.